# IndexError: tuple index out of range in python for drawing graph

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

```
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from([[1,2], [2,3], [1,3], [1,4], [1,5], [3,5],
                  [6,7], [7,8], [8,9], [6,9], [6,8], [7,9],
                  [10,11], [11,12], [10,12],
                  [9, 12], [2, 7]
                  ])
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, node_color='r')
```

File "C:...\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\networkx\utils\decorators.py", line 396, in _random_state
random_state_arg = args[random_state_index]
IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: Can you please share some code?

Comment: so where is the problem for me!